# GeoFire on iOS with Firebase 5

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, geofire

The update from Firebase 4.x to Firebase 5.0.0 broke my GeoFire installation. I was installing GeoFire via "Podfile" like this:

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

I now receive this error message:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "Firebase/Database": In Podfile: Firebase/Database
>
> GeoFire (from `https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git`) was
>   resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on   Firebase/Database (~> 4.0) Specs
>   satisfying the Firebase/Database, Firebase/Database (~> 4.0)
>   dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment
>   target.

The deployment target in Podfile as well as in the Xcode project is iOS 11. So there really is no higher minimum deployment target.

Cloning the repo locally and changing the installation to

```
pod 'GeoFire', :path => '/Users/georg/Projekte/Repos/geofire-objc'
```

and raising the dependency to Firebase 5.0 does not seem to work either as I now receive the error message

> [!] The 'Pods-poifinder' target has transitive dependencies that
>   include static frameworks: (FirebaseDatabase, FirebaseCore,
>   FirebaseAuth, FirebaseFirestore, FirebaseFunctions, and
>   FirebaseStorage)

Firebase has switched to source pods with v5.0.0 which might be an explanation for this.

My question is now: How do I get GeoFire to work with Firebase 5.0 in a Swift 4.1 project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until this is fixed in the repository you can use this workaround:

1. Clone the repository locally
2. Edit your podfile and point to the local repository like this

   pod 'GeoFire', :path => '/Users/hans/repos/geofire-objc'
3. In "GeoFire.podspec" in the local repository edit the dependency like this

   s.ios.dependency 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.0'
4. Add this line to "GeoFire.podspec":

   s.static_framework = true
5. Run

   pod update